# Allow wild card characters in make file

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, gnu-make, automake

I have an application which runs on windows and Linux.
It is having a make file which is generated at run-time.
Now the problem is the make file points to folder path which is having special characters like @#$%! as some path.

But since these characters have different meaning 
Ex.$ searches for its definition
    # refers to comment

the compilation fails.

Do you have any resolution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is located in the directory with the special characters in its name? Is it sources, object files, the makefile itself? Anything else?

Comment: it contains the object files
For Ex:OBJECTS = \
 D:/PR/9354/lib_15_#$@%&/submodels/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV15.o \

Comment: As far as I can tell it's very tedious to deal with special characters in make. Of course I can't tell - but I could imagine that'd be easier to just get rid of those special characters in the first place.

Comment: Btw.: I saw you have windows paths. Different make binaries support different paths. Currently I cannot recall the exact differences but you probably want to have a look into msys make and mingw make - which are NOT the same. Cygwin make most probably won't fit for those kind of paths.

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash before the digits, so use a \ before them, like so : \#

Comment: there will be many such combinations like you suggested.
Do you have any reference where list of all the escape sequence will be listed?
One more doubt..Are these escape sequence different in windows and linux

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating literal filenames inside your *Makefile*:

```
# This won't work
OBJECTS := D:/PR/9354/lib_15_#$@%&/submodels/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV‌​15.o
$(info [${OBJECTS}])
```

AFAICS the only special characters you have to take care of in *make* itself are `$` and `#`.

`$` always introduces macro expansion.
The work-around is to double all dollars:
`$$` expands to the value of the variable with the name `$`, which is `$`.

`#` starts a comment.
Replace with `\#`.

```
# This works
OBJECTS := D:/PR/9354/lib_15_\#$$@%&/submodels/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV‌​15.o
$(info [${OBJECTS}])
```

If you are getting your filenames from an invocation of `$(wildcard ...)` say,
you won't have to worry about the above.

However, your shell will certainly be confused by all these characters.
For instance, `$` causes parameter expansion on *bash*, `&` runs a command in the background on *bash* etc.

The safest thing to do here is to quote all filenames before invoking the shell.
Surround each filename with single quotes `'` if your shell is *bash*.
If you are using the windows shell (*cmd*), then you will have to use double quotes.
(Your life will be hell if you are using *cmd* due to its insane quoting rules.)

So, assuming *bash*

```
$ cat Makefile
OBJECTS := D:/PR/9354/lib_15_\#$$@%&/submodels/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV‌​15.o
QUOTED := $(patsubst %,'%',${OBJECTS})

.PHONY: all
all:
    echo ${QUOTED}
```

giving

```
$ make --warn
echo 'D:/PR/9354/lib_15_#$@%&/submodels/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV‌​15.o'
D:/PR/9354/lib_15_#$@%&/submodels/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV‌​15.o
```

Sheesh.

### Edit

The easiest thing to do of course is to avoid *make*'s parser,
and simply read the unmolested filenames using `$(file …)`.

```
$ cat names
D:/PR/9354/lib_15_#$@%&/submodels:=/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV‌​15.o

$ cat Makefile
OBJECTS := $(file < names)

.PHONY: all
all:
        echo $(patsubst %,'%',${OBJECTS})

$ make
echo 'D:/PR/9354/lib_15_#$@%&/submodels:=/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV‌​15.o'
D:/PR/9354/lib_15_#$@%&/submodels:=/win32-gcc/CONS00_ABHI_REV‌​15.o
```

The name even includes the problematic `:=`, as pointed out by @Vroomfondel.

Comment: Also `$` is make's macro expansion character (in the case shown `$@` refers to the target of the rule being executed) so you have to be doubly careful.  You should have used `\$$@` to expand it correctly.

Comment: Depending on the type of line where the special characters appear, also the `:` and the `=` can pose a problem (e.g. some `$(eval )` construct)

Answer (score 0):

Once make finds literal characters like `#` or `:` or `$` in a line where their special meaning is an allowed parsing solution, it will interpret them as such. Your best bet is to modify the generator of the makefile, and rewrite the output filter for the path names to replace all such characters with their "defused" quoting sequence.  The other way to avoid this is to preprocess the makefile and replace the problematic appearances, but I think this is much harder than changing file name output. 
In any case you need some extra variable definitions in your makefile which will serve as quoting constructs:

```
space := $(strip) $(strip)#
comma := ,#
hash := \##
percent := %#
colon := :#
equal := =#
paropen := (#
parclose := )#
```

`$` is escaped by `$$` as usual. This lets you define all kinds of nasty strings now:

```
evilstring := $(space)D$(colon)/PR/9354/lib_15_$(hash)$$@$(percent)&/etc...
```

While the other answers were right that in variable assignemnts only `$` and `#` have to be escaped, I don't know if your generator will insert filenames in other places:

something like

```
 D:\home\myfile.o:
```

or

```
 \home\lib_1_&=@!\myfile.o:
```

as target name could cause problems.

You may want to take a look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which now even has glob-matching (e.g. `$(call glob-match,$(shell uname -sr),Linux 4.[7-9].*)`) although this may not help with your problem.